# Continuity of Galois action under changing the topology of G-set to a coarser one.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory

Questions:

> (1) Let $K$ be a number field and $\overline{K}$ an algebraic closure.
> Let $G=Gal(\overline{K}/K)$ the absolute Galois group endowed with the
> profinite topology, and $M$ some topological space endowed with a
> $G$-action. Suppose the $G$-action over $X$  is continuous w.r.t the
> discrete topology, does this imply it is also continuous w.r.t a
> coarser topology?
>
> (2) The same question as (1), but instead we assume $K$ is a local field (a
> discrete valuation field with a perfect residue field).

Remarks:

(1) This question is a continuation of:
[Continuity of $G$-action under changing the topology of $G$-set to a coarser one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199556/continuity-of-g-action-under-changing-the-topology-of-g-set-to-a-coarser-one)

(2) The remark given by Moishe Kohan below gives a counter-example for the question.

Comment: The same example of $Z/2$-action as in the answer to the other question works here too, with $K={\mathbb Q}$, since $Gal(\bar Q/Q)$ admits (continuous) epimorphisms to $Z/2$, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183074/galois-theory-converts-problems-in-field-theory-to-problems-in-group-theory-can/4183818#4183818).

Comment: Thanks @MoisheKohan for the remark!

Comment: @Moishe Kohan : Sorry maybe I didn't get the point. Did you mean that  $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ (endowed with profinite topology) acting over $\mathbb{R}$ by factoring through $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and then acts (as in the answer of the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199556/continuity-of-g-action-under-changing-the-topology-of-g-set-to-a-coarser-one),  is a counter-example?

Comment: Of course......

Comment: @Moishe Kohan : I see, this is a clever observation and it works, maybe also works for $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$? However, what really in my mind was to look for the situation where the question has positive answer. But by your remark, the restriction that $G$ is endowed with the profinite topology is almost useless... I don't even know how to change the question now. Anyway, thanks again for the nice remark!

Comment: $Q_p$ is not a number field and you assumed that $K$ is. I do not know of any interesting situation where your question has positive answer.

Comment: Yes, I mean for the local field case in question (2). Thanks for the remarks.